# Finding the biggest diagonal element of a square matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to find the max. diagonal element of a square matrix (let's take a `2x2` matrix as an example; assume `n = 2`).

My logic is based on comparing `[i][i]` to `[i + 1][i + 1]` (the first element of a diagonal matrix compared to the next diagonal element).

Example input:

`2`

`1 2 3 4`

Example output:

*First we print out the complete matrix*:

`1 2`

`3 4`

Then we print out the diagonal elements only:

Diagonal elements: `1` `4`

Max. diagonal matrix element: `4206628` - this is where I'm not sure why it's messing up. The maximum diagonal element is supposed to be `4` in this case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int i, j, n, max = 0;

scanf("%d", &n);

int MAT[n][n];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
        scanf("%d", &MAT[i][j]);
    }
}

 for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
        printf("%d\t", MAT[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}   printf("\n");

for (i = 0; i < n; i++){

    printf("%d\t", MAT[i][i]);
    printf("\n");


    if (MAT[i][i] > MAT[i + 1][i + 1]){
        max = MAT[i][i];
    }   else max = MAT[i + 1][i + 1];

}

printf("\nMax. diagonal matrix element: %d", max);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the latter loop you're comparing MAT[1][1] (wich is 4) with MAT[2][2] (wich is uninitialized memory so its value is undefined, in your case 4206628). You're not writing the right algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be coming from `else max = MAT[i + 1][i + 1]`. Since `MAT[i + 1][i + 1]` is not always defined (imagine when `i = 1`, you go out of the array length), a random value is read from memory. The way I would solve this problem you be to change the condition where you change the `max` value.

```
if (MAT[i][i] > max) // replacing max when the current value is bigger
{
    max = MAT[i][i];
}
// else not necessary
```

Using this snippet would not work if the array was filled with negative number since `max` is initialized at `0`.

Comment: Start with `int max = INT_MIN;` to properly handle an array with all negative values.